# Connection to node -1 could not be established

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I installed zookeeper and kafka docker container on virtual machine. MY settings look like

```
 zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    name:zookeeper
ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
  ports:
  - "2181:2181"

kafka:
   image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
   hostname: kafka
 ports:
     - "9092:9092"
     - "29092:29092"
   depends_on:
     - zookeeper
   KAFKA_BROKER_ID: "-1"
   KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181");
   ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
   KAFKA_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://9092, PLAINTEXT_HOST://29092"
   KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092, PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092"
   KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT"
   KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "PLAINTEXT"
   KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
   AUTO.LEADER.REBALANCE.ENABLE: "true"
   KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE: "true"
   KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
```

Now i am trying to send some message from my local machine to kafka, but i am getting the following error.

```
  Connection to node -1 (//ip-of-virtualmachine:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

From my local machine i configure kafka producer to send messages. the property in my code which configure the bootstrap server is

```
 String bootstrapServers = "virtual-machine-ip:29092";
 Properties kafka-properties = new Properties();
 kafka-properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
 .
 .
 .
 create producer and send some record etc.
```

All the example i find over internet are regarding the docker and kafka. None of them are related to kafka, docker and virtual machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get this compose file from? It's misconfigured...

Comment: @cricket_007 I create this compose file according to my requirement by viewing different compose files. How can i configure it properly? thanks.

Comment: Why create your own? The Confluent Docker quickstart one works fine

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't expose port of your kafka container to your host, try to expose port 29092 via:

```
ports:
 - "29092:29092"
```

or run your container in host network `docker -d --net=host...` if you run it from docker-compose add `network_mode: host` to your services

to fix your docker config you can take inspiration here:
https://github.com/simplesteph/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-single-kafka-single.yml

Comment: I would also omit KAFKA_BROKER_ID: "-1"

Comment: I exposed those ports but no luck. when sending some messages from my local machine to the kafka docker which is installed on virtual machine, which ip should i use?

Comment: ip address of that VM machine

Comment: I used that ip but getting that same error.  I expose the required ports as well.

Comment: can you ping that machine? also, check on your VM if the port is open by `sudo netstat -nlp | grep :29092`

Comment: I would advise having a look on docker config I provided link for

Comment: I check and the port is open. the output is like              tcp6       0      0 :::29092                 :::*                    LISTEN      4379/docker-proxy
 Also i follow that same docker config you provide in the link. . the error is then  Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established

Comment: what if you try port `:29092`?

Comment: then i get this error in forever loop mean it continue appear on screen: ERROR Sender:237 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Uncaught error in kafka producer I/O thread: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No entry found for connection 1

Comment: when kafka docker container is up. it mean kafka server is running. right? i do not need to give the command like in my local machine to start the  kafka . 
zookeeper-server-start.sh .\config\zookeeper.properties

Comment: No, its automaticaly started within the cointainer from the image, thats a nature of docker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208782/discussion-between-rio-and-stefan-repcek).

Answer (score 0):

If your code is running outside of the VM, you'll need to make you have an external port forward from the VM to the host, and through the container.

By the way , Docker Machine would create VMs for you, rather than you installing Docker in one on your own

Comment: My code is running on my local machine. I want to send some data to the kafka which is installed on virtual machine. I tried with the above suggestion also, but in that case i am getting same error. I use docker ip as well as virtual machine ip but no success.

Comment: when i am running code on my local machine, then to access kafka container in virtual machine, which ip and port should i use?

Comment: If you properly setup the port forward in the VM settings, then you would continue to use localhost 29092, however, it's not clear if your services are starting correctly because like I said, your shown compose file is incorrect